# VBA - How to call a module with arguments from Application.Run?

Tags: vba, ms-access, regression

This is driving me nuts.

Using VBA Access, I'm attempting to set up a regression testing suite for a database application we're developing. I want to traverse a table, and call each module and function listed in the table using Application.Run (that way, when a developer creates a new feature, they can just create their regression test module, and list it in the table).

I would assume I would do this with Application.Run.

The code snippet I have works:

```
If folderName <> "" Then
    Dim test1 As String: test1 = "regCOTSImporter"
    Dim test2 As String: test2 = "regressionTestCOTS"

    Application.Run regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS(foldername)
End If
```

Now, I would assume that

```
Application.Run regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS, foldername
```

would work as well, but it does not, because VBA fails at finding the procedure claiming that the argument is not optional (even though the documentation for Application.Run lists further arguments as parameters...)

However, ideally I want regCOTSImporter and regressionTestCOTS to be replaced by test1 and test2 respectively, as Dim'd above -- that way instead I load them from the DB. However, if I do the following:

```
 Application.run test1 & "." test2 & "(" & foldername & ")"
```

I get a message saying that the procedure cannot be found. What do I need to do in order to be able to call this module.function from a String?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This: `Application.Run regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS(foldername)` shouldn't work afaik, since `Application.Run` takes a string as argument. Do you really want to have multiple modules with public, conflicting function names? If not, you can omit the module name.

Comment: ... I don't know why, but that did it. Dropping the regCOTSImporter (the module name) and only using the function name works for a variable reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct version of your second example is

`Application.Run "regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS", foldername`

Therefore, you can simply use

`Application.run test1 & "." test2, foldername`

for the general case, as `test1 & "." test2` is already a string.

Comment: I used `Application.Run test1 & "." & test2, folderName` and still got Runtime Error 2517: Access cannot find the procedure 'regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS.'

Comment: Is `regCOTSImporter` definitely a Module, and not a UserForm or anything else?

Comment: Certainly a module, and within the same project.

Comment: Chalk it up to one of those mysteries of MsAccess.

Comment: It seems that Access has a different syntax for `Application.Run` than I am used to. Try just `Application.Run test2, folderName`. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the module, so you'll have to be more careful about name clashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Run "'" & test1 & "." & test2 & "(""" & FolderName & """)'"
```

The string you're supplying looks like this

```
'regCOTSImporter.regressionTestCOTS("testfname")'
```

Assuming your `FolderName` variable is set to `testfname`

Comment: Still fails to find the procedure - interestingly, however, the error message omits the first '